# React extends defautProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still on the way of the conquest React. I prefer to use a es6 component-based approach when creating React classes. And I detained at the moment when it is necessary to inheritance of some existing class with already defined defaultProps static property.

```
import {Component} from 'react';

class MyBox extends Component {

}

// Define defaultProps for MyBox
MyBox.defaultProps = {
    onEmptyMessage: 'Nothing at here'
}
```

When I define a static property defaultProps of class that extend MyBox, it completely overwrites defaultProps of parent class.

```
class MyItems extends MyBox {
    render() {
         // this.props.onEmptyMessage is undefined here
         // but this.props.onRemoveMessage is present
         return <i>{this.props.onEmptyMessage}</i>; //<i></i>
    }
}
// Define defaultProps for MyItems
MyItems.defaultProps = {
    onRemoveMessage: 'Are you sure?'
}
```

But i need to extend defaultProps of parent class, not overwrite. I understand that is possible by extending directly defaultProps property of parent class.

```
MyItems.defaultProps = _.extend(MyBox.defaultProps, {
    onRemoveMessage: 'Are you sure?'
});
```

But i think that such trick is dirty. Is there a way to perform it according to React plan?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you the issue is not how you can merge the properties but how you can compose it without extending. You would have your components like this:

```
class MyBox extends Component {

  static defaultProps = { title: 'Box title' }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className={'mybox ' + this.props.className}>
          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
          {this.prop.children}
        </div>
    )
  }

}

class MyItems extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <MyBox className="itembox" title="Items title">
          <i>{this.props.children}</i>
        </MyBox>
    )
  }

}
```

Then use it like that

```
<MyBox>
  box
</MyBox>
```

or

```
<MyItems>
  items box
</MyItems>
```

That will render:

```
<div class="mybox">
    <h1>Box title</h1>
    box
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="mybox itembox">
    <h1>Items title</h1>
    <i>items box</i>
</div>
```

It looks like you have extending/overriding the className or the title, but you have composed. If you use this way of building your UI, you'll see it will be easier and faster

Comment: Your concept is clear. But what if I do not need to have render() method in parent class? In my case myBox is a pattern for creating many others classes with own render() methods and functionality based on parent class methods and predefined values.

Comment: Then you can use decorator, IMO, it is made for that